# Searching JSON file for string - Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to learn python and get stuck on following:

This is REST API output (i attached client:AP)

I run multiple `requests` queries and getting different clients and CC-XXX values

```
data=response.content + " client:AP"
print data


      {"id":"21984","key":"CC-2891","self":"https://jira.company.com/rest/api/latest/issue/21984"} client:AP
```

I need to extract key values (CC-2891) and client AP (sometimes client is not AP) into 2 different variables

Desired output `CC-281` and `client AP`

```
import re

result = re.findall(r'\bkey:(\S+)\s, data)
print result
```

but getting nothing

tried also

```
print data['key']
```

but got:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: You're receiving a `dict`, but you appear to try and parse the whole `dict` as a `str`. Just use `data['key']` instead, for example.

Comment: Why do you add `" client:AP"` to the response? Slso, why ddo you mention "File" in the question title? Is this pertinent?

Comment: `print data['key']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: @doctorlove:corrected title: i added client:AP in order to distinguish client, i run 2 REST API calls and need,for each client to send email with `CC-XXXX` and client code

Comment: The requests module can decode JSON for you. Use  `data=response.json()`. Otherwise, use the standard `json` module. Don't try to parse a JSON string or file yourself.

Comment: You have turned it into a string by adding a string and made it impossible for yourself. Keep a distionary of responses? Or append this extra info to the JSON?

Comment: thanks @doctorlove, i though i can just append it.Thank You, i'll hard-code AP into email body then, it was important for me just to get CC-XXXX value. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a json response. Use the `json` module.

**Ex:**

```
import json
data = """{"id":"21984","key":"CC-2891","self":"https://jira.company.com/rest/api/latest/issue/21984"}"""
data = json.loads(data)
print(data["key"])
```

**Output:**

```
CC-2891
```

If you are using the `requests` module then you can directly use  `response.json()`

**Ex:**

```
data=response.json()
print(data["key"])
```

Comment: This won't work because his `data` is not pure JSON but has this `Client:AP` appended to the end. You would need to strip that away first.

Comment: That is appended by the user --> `response.content + " client:AP"`

Comment: yes, that works, any way i can somehow get value `Client:AP` ?

Comment: @pythonbeginner. I do not understand `Client:AP ` how are you getting this value?

Comment: Is it a dictionary or string?

Comment: it's just plain string

Comment: If it is just plain text, and you are manually appending it...I do not understand why it is hard to extract....

Comment: Instead of appending it, it makes more sense to store it in a dictionary like `{ "Client: AP": data }`

Comment: thanks @JanSteinke, it works, Rakesh, maybe it's easy for you but for me it's extremly complex :)

Answer (score 0):

Your error,

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

is because you have appended `" client:AP"` to the response.

If you want pairs of clients and the corresponding key, maybe store these yourself in a dictionary?

Like

```
lookup = {}
lookup["AP"] = response.json()["key"]
```

Then get the next response, and store that against something other than `"AP"`.